# how to install Hadoop2.7.1(single node setup) on Vmware

Tags: linux, hadoop, cmd, vmware

I was following the instruction on the official website:
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

there are two problems I can't solve:
1. I can't run these commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ssh
$ sudo apt-get install rsync
```

[picture_apt-get_commandnotfound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gdy9N.jpg)

2. the website says: Unpack the downloaded Hadoop distribution. In the distribution, edit the file etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh to define some parameters as follows

I can't find this file: etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh

I have downloaded these files and uncompressed them:

```
hadoop-2.7.1.tar.gz
hadoop-2.7.1-src.tar.gz
hadoop-2.7.1.tar.gz.mds
hadoop-2.7.1-src.tar.gz.mds
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will have ssh already. No need to install ssh again.

You can follow these [instructions](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLf0swTFhTI8pFYbcZA4bNWCjetRKVubPH) to set up Hadoop on VM. The instructions are mainly for Centos (redhat flavor). It works for Redhat, CentOS and Fedora.

How did you uncompress the files. You should use `tar xzf hadoop-2.7.1.tar.gz`. It will create directory with name hadoop-2.7.1. Then you need to cd to it and then you will find etc directory.

If you have hadoop-2.7.1.tar.gz in /home/. Then you need to go to /home//hadoop-2.7.1/etc/hadoop. Also you can find the location of hadoop directory by using `find / -name "hadoop" -type d` command. It will search your VM and report all the directories with name hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

I have a write-up for installing single-node using VirtualBox and CentOS 6.5 here: https://github.com/trisberg/hadoop-install/blob/master/InstallingHadoop.adoc

Hopefully this provides some help.